# How to specify branch link in ios14 app install Facebook campaign

Tags: ios14, branch.io, facebook-ads, skadnetwork

On the Branch docs it says to use a Branch deep link when creating a Facebook ad. However, if the campaign is set to "App install" and iOS14, the option to set a deep link disappears.

How do I associate the campaign with Branch then? I'm purely using SKAdNetwork for attribution.

Comment: Where you able to find an answer at all? I'm in the same boat...